# Keyframing driver location results in unwanted movement of armature and animation

Tags: animation, objects, armature, drivers

first time posting here! I've reached a bit of an impass. Ultimately I want to hide an object for all animations except one.

To do this, I am attempting to use a driver, `OutsideOrbDriver` to control the material value `Fac` for `NightOrb_outside`. I have mapped `OutsideOrbDriver`'s X location value to `Fac` so that when I adjust the X location value from 0 to 1 of `OutsideOrbDriver` the `Fac` value of `NightOrb_outside` shifts from 0 to 1. Working as expected.

The problem comes when I attempt to animate the Object `OutsideOrbDriver`. First note that when I select `OutsideOrbDriver`, I see the actions for the entire armature even though `OutsideOrbDriver` is not a part of the armature.

[image: OutsideOrbDriver displays all idle animation keyframes]

Further, when I move the location of `OutsideOrbDriver` and keyframe with `i > apply location` the entire armature moves to the position of `OutsideOrbDriver`. I would expect this if the armature was linked to the object. But it isn't. I am dealing with two separate objects.

[image: NyxArmature moves to location of OutsideOrbDriver after keyframing]

Could someone explain to me why my entire armature and animation is moving to the location of the `OutsideOrbDriver`. Is there a way to prevent this?Thank you for the assistance!

Blender File:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OutsideOrbDriver and the armature are sharing the same action:

[image]

Then when you move the OutsideOrbDriver, and with *"auto keying"* on:

[image]

the movement impacts all the elements inside the action.

Comment: Thank you lemon, this answers my question! 

Do you know if there is a clean way to separate different actions between different objects. There only seems to be one action list.

Comment: Use "stash" button when the empty is selected. That will disconnect it to the action. Or delete this empty and add another one.